# Adding Date in a file - C

Tags: c, file, date, file-io, time.h

I'm coding a network game in C. I 've written scores in a file. I also wanted to add the date of the day.
Here is the file's structure : Date Name Score
and the code :

```
ScoreFile = fopen("scores.txt", "a");
fprintf(ScoreFile, "%s %d\n", Name, Score);
```

I've tried system("date") but it's printed on stdout. I think that I can't add the Date with fprintf.

Do you know a solution that permits to add Date in a file ? (maybe something from time.h ?)

thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [strftime](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strfti.html) to convert the time structure to string.

Example (from link above):

```
#include <time.h>
// ...

char s[30];
size_t i;
struct tm tim;
time_t now;
now = time(NULL);
tim = *(localtime(&now));
i = strftime(s,30,"%b %d, %Y; %H:%M:%S\n",&tim);
```

puts `Jul 9, 2011; 17:55:55\n` in `s`

Comment: Thanks It's works !  but the date in file : Date: Saturday 09, 2011; 00:00:28 is on two lines instead of only one. Is there is a solution ?

Comment: If I get you right, remove the `\n` at the end of the string, otherwise we'll need to see what you did.

Comment: I'm glad. be aware that you can change the format to contain only the details that you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
time_t now;
time(&now);

printf("... %s\n", ctime(&now));
```

If you need to specify your own format, look into [`strftime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html). If you later need to read it back and parse it, you might be better off writing the number of seconds since epoch (the `time_t`, perhaps in ASCII?).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
fprintf(ScoreFile, "[%s] %s %d\n", ctime(&now), Name, Score);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **strptime**, **strftime** and **mktime** from time.h.

To parse:

```
struct tm timeStruct = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char *timeBuf = "03061983";
char *p = strptime(timeBuf, "%d%b%y", &timeStruct);

if (p != NULL)
{
    // manipulate timeStruct.
    // use mktime to get the time_t value
}
```

To write:

```
  time_t t;
  struct tm * timeStruct;
  char timeBuf[6];

  time(&t);
  timeStruct = localtime(&t);

  strftime (timeBuf, 6, "%d%b%y", timeStruct)
```

Regards,
Yusuf